# Have Writing Beside Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have two divs (one with an embedded YouTube video sitting over an image, and another is text) sit side-by-side.  I would usually do this with the `float: left;` rule, however it's trickier with the CSS/HTML combo for the video over the image.

How can I go about doing this?

My code:

```css
.backgroundimage {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  right: 390px;
  float: left;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundimage">
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>Hi, this is some test text!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any text in your HTML code.

Comment: I added some text to it.  Thanks for telling me!

Comment: Please check the code in the Answer  I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkjqp3o8/) to see it wroking.

So I think instead of using `<img/>` you can use the CSS property to display image in the background. The CSS code:

```
.backgroundimage {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png") no-repeat;
  height:329px;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
} 
p{
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  width:140px;
}
```

**Edited** Check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkjqp3o8/3/) for a responsive text

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.  All my characters are vertical, and go way down into the footer.

Comment: Just comment or remove the line: `width: 505px;` from `.backgroundimage`. I forgot to update the fiddle before posting the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap on your page.
Grab bootstrap CND on the site..

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

And now try this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
           <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Hi, this is some test text!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`

```css
.backgroundimage {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  right: 390px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Youtube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  bottom: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundimage">
  <img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tvscreen.png" alt="null" />
  <iframe class="Youtube" width="479" height="269" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ydYvG52K-E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>Hi, this is some test text!</p>
</div>
```